# Do Universal Links on iOS applications always go through the browser first?

Tags: ios, cordova, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

For some context, I am using a cordova application with this plugin: [ionic-plugin-deeplinks](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-deeplinks). This might be irrelevant to my main question though.

I have Universal Links configured for my application, as well as my associated domain, etc. When I click a link in my app that leads to my associated domain, it is currently opening the safari browser, with a banner that says "Open in App".

Is there a way to simply continue within the app, as opposed to having the user be directed to the browser and then relying on the user to hit the "Open in App" banner?

Comment: I think that the problem is you are opening the link from within the app; Apple assumes that if the app could handle the link it wouldn't have asked the system to open it; it would have just navigated to the correct place directly, so the intention must have been to open the link in the browser.  If everything is configured correctly, then as a test you should be able to put the link in, say Notes, and have it open your app directly.

Comment: I see. For my usecase, I want the link to take the user to the proper resource in the app. It is a weblink. Is this possible with Universal Links?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use universal links for this.  If you are using a web view you need to intercept the navigation request, identify that it is a request that your app can handle directly and then navigate within your app.